# How do you force VMware Workstation VM to synchronize its date and time with host?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, sync, vmware, vmware-workstation

Sometimes when I resume a virtual machine, the date and time continues from where it was when I paused the VM.

This causes some issues with cookies, tokens, and other things.

Is there any way I can force the VM to look at the date and time of the host machine and synchronize?

Comment: What is the guest OS? Different virtualized OSes may behave differently. As well, what virtualization software are you using?

Comment: It's a Windows 10 guest on a Windows 10 host. The vm software is VMWare 14 Workstation (see tags)

Comment: If you have VMware Tools installed in the guest, this should happen automatically after resuming the VM.

Comment: @jamesdlin It doesn't though. That's what's odd

Comment: Verify that the "Synchronize guest time with host" is checked under the VM's Settings-->Options-->VMware Tools

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring when I paused my VM while a debugging process in Visual Studio was running. It seems the running process blocks and synchronization of the time.

To solve this I stopped the process and paused the machine. Then when I resume, the time is correct.